# d3 returns incorrect week start

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I have the following date: `2015-23` in the format `%Y-%W` which is Week 23 of 2015 (June 1st, 2015 - 7th June 2015).

When I use the format method in d3 to return the date for that week:

`var cameron = d3.time.format('%Y-%W').parse;`

`cameron('2015-23');`

It returns `Mon Jun 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

But I should of got: `Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

According to the docs at: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md `%W` should be `week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53].` But instead it's jumping ahead a week!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected result. According to Mike Bostock:

> The %W directive used by d3-time-format is not the ISO week date; it is the zero-based Monday-of-year in [00, 53]. This means that the first Monday in any given year is always number 1; any date prior to this first Monday in the same year is 0.

By "ISO week date", he means this (ISO 8061): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

So, still according to him:

- 2015-00 is Monday, December 29, 2014.
- 2015-01 is Monday, January 5, 2015.
- 2015-52 and 2016-00 is Monday, December 28, 2015.
- 2015-53 and 2016-01 is Monday, January 4, 2016.

Comment: I have no control over what the weeks that come back are... So what's the solution? Just subrtact 1 from the week number before parsing?

Comment: You can do that, or use another library/method to get the ISO week.